# Sandboxing IE on metro interface

Tags: virtualization, sandbox, windows-8, internet-explorer

I hold a **tablet** with *Windows 8.1*.
When I'm on the *desktop interface* I do use Sandboxie for normal internet usage to prevent having Windows infected.

I wonder if there is a way to do the same with the IE app on the metro interface:

- Is it possible to **sandboxe** Internet Explorer both on desktop and **metro interface**?

Comment: So I don't know the answer to the question that you actually asked, but.... I can tell you that Metro (or, what used to be called Metro) IE in Windows 8/8.1 *already* uses sandboxing protection. Metro IE makes use of something called Enhanced Protected Mode, introduced in Windows 8/8.1.  EPM is a feature that places the rendering engine in Metro IE  within the general Windows sandboxing technology introduced in 8/8.1,  AppContainer.  Details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

Comment: AppContainer is also the sandbox that protects the Edge browser in Windows 10.  One other (perhaps) interesting thing:  Enhanced Protected Mode is enabled by default with Metro IE, but if you wish you actually can turn it on in *desktop* IE as well.  (You'll find a checkbox in Internet Options/Advanced screen.)  If using Sandboxie ever becomes a hassle that might be an alternative  worth thinking about.  (I make no guarantee that turning on EPM would be as secure overall as using Sandboxie to sandbox the whole desktop IE program, but it would certainly be an improvement vs doing nothing)